Compress jpg with zopfli prevents jpg to be shown on EVE2 display
In order to save flash data and SPI traffic, I'm trying to compress my JPG images with zopfli before sending them to NHD-7.0-800480FT-CSXV-CTP. I'm using this library and an ESP32-S3.
For reference, using this procedure I can successfully show the image on the display:

given a jpg image, convert it to C code: xxd -i <image>.jpg | tee output.c | wc -w
add the size in the array and adjust the header, basicall I want the following stuff:

#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H
    
#if !defined(PROGMEM)
    #define PROGMEM
#endif
    
extern const unsigned char IMG[1074] PROGMEM;
    
#endif // IMAGE_H

and:
#if !defined(PROGMEM)
    #define PROGMEM
#endif

unsigned char IMG_LOGO[1074] = {
  0x94, 0x4d, 0x03, 0x52, 0x85, 0x61, 0x14, 0x3d, 0x1f, 0x9e, 0x79, 0xff,
  0x97, 0xed, 0x1a, 0x64, 0xdb, 0xf6, 0x20, 0xdb, 0x36, 0xc7, 0x2d, 0xa1,
  0x15, 0xc5, 0x0d, 0x34, 0xca, 0x5a, 0x46, 0xfc, 0x91, 0x6b, 0xd8, 0xb9,
  0x77, 0x74, 0xa8, 0x9e, 0xa9, 0x77, 0xf0, 0x36, 0xd4, 0xd4, 0xd7, 0x80,
  // ...
};


transfer the jpg image to the EVE2 controller:

#define MEM_IMG 0x000f8000

EVE_init_spi();
EVE_init();

EVE_cmd_loadimage(MEM_IMG, 0, IMG, sizeof(IMG));
EVE_color_rgb(COLOR_WHITE);
EVE_cmd_dl(DL_BEGIN | EVE_BITMAPS);
EVE_cmd_setbitmap(MEM_IMG, EVE_RGB565, 57, 60);
EVE_cmd_dl(VERTEX2F(100 * 16, 100 * 16));
EVE_cmd_dl(DL_END);


it works!

Now I want to compress the jpg with the deflate algorithm as specified at page 166 of the above manual:

CMD_INFLATE - decompress data into memory
Decompress the following compressed data into RAM_G. The data should have been compressed
with the DEFLATE algorithm, e.g. with the ZLIB library. This is particularly useful for loading
graphics data.

so I issue:
zopfli --v --deflate image.jpg

I convert to C code as above (now its size is reduced to 973 bytes) and this time I use cmd_inflate to trasfer it to the display:
#define MEM_IMG 0x000f8000

EVE_init_spi();
EVE_init();

EVE_cmd_inflate(MEM_IMG, IMG, sizeof(IMG)); 
EVE_color_rgb(COLOR_WHITE);
EVE_cmd_dl(DL_BEGIN | EVE_BITMAPS);
EVE_cmd_setbitmap(MEM_IMG, EVE_RGB565, 57, 60);
EVE_cmd_dl(VERTEX2F(100 * 16, 100 * 16));
EVE_cmd_dl(DL_END);

but the display does not show the image.
Where did I go wrong?

I only had time for a few minutes of research on zopfli and I could not tell if its deflate operation is lossless. If deflate is intended for image data, then there's a good chance that it is not lossless (i.e. doing a compress/decompress does not produce bit-for-bit the same data). But be aware that jpg is already a compressed format, and MUST be reproduced exactly as-is. If you want to use a compression that is better than jpg, you'll have to run it on an uncompressed (raw) image format.

How do you expect the JPEG decoder chip to make sense of a non-JPEG bitstream? Zopfli will try its best to losslessly compress almost anything (but it might actually make a non-trivial JPEG larger!). Its idea of deflate may not be quite what the chip expects (ZLIB). I suggest you take a look at p156 of the chipset manual. JPEG files are quite close to optimum all you will do is slow things down by trying to compress them some other way (unless they are low content ones). Only the guff in the JPEG headers is uncompressed (you could strip some of that out if it is present).

"DEFLATE" is an algorithm, it's not a bitstream format specification.
Generally, you'll need a decompressor which can specifically handle the bitstream the compressor produces.
A quick search seems to reveal that on FT800/EVE "zlib inflate is supported", so only zlib, no zopfli.
Also, it looks like you can use JPEG or inflate for an image, not both on the same data.

Got it! I clearly mis-understood https://github.com/RudolphRiedel/FT800-FT813/discussions/96#discussioncomment-6734637 and https://github.com/RudolphRiedel/FT800-FT813/blob/5.x/examples/EVE_Test_ESP32_PlatformIO/src/tft_data.c#L79

Just a clarification. You wrote you can use JPEG or inflate for an image. But what does that mean? The image is already in JPEG since the graphic controller can display only JPEG or PNG images
